# Geb Spock test case is not getting execute from command line however same is executed successfully by Intellij

Tags: groovy, spock, geb, gmaven-plugin

I am using Geb Spock maven with athaydes reports.
When I integrated athaydes reports I am able to execute test case from Intellij IDE and its giving proper reports as well.
However when I do execute it from command it gives me error related to missing dependency.

Strange part is that when I follow below sequence of execution steps Reports are successfully getting generated

- Scenario 1:

  - mvn clean
  - Now, execute test case from Intellij. (Reports are successfully generated)
  - Now, execute same test case from command line by using below command:

  $ mvn -Dtest=spec/sprintOne/TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec test

Reports are sucesfully generated

- Scenario 2:

  - mvn clean
  - Now, execute same test case from command line by using below command:

    $ mvn -Dtest=spec/sprintOne/TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec test

Giving below error message:

```
C:\DurgeshProjectWork\Workspace\IdeaProjects\bdd_geb_spock>mvn -Dtest=spec/sprintOne/TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bdd_geb_spock 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.4:testCompile (default) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.585 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-27T13:48:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/127M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4:testCompile (default) on project bdd_geb_spock: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4:testCompile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:g
maven-plugin:1.4:testCompile: Unable to load class org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector due to missing dependency org/junit/runners/model/MultipleFailureException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/gmaven-plugin/1.4/gmaven-plugin-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-1.8/1.4/gmaven-runtime-1.8-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-support/1.4/gmaven-feature-support-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.8.2/ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.14/groovy-all-2.4.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4/spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-api/1.4/gmaven-runtime-api-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-api/1.4/gmaven-feature-api-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-loader/1.4/gmaven-runtime-loader-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-support/1.4/gmaven-runtime-support-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gshell/gshell-io/2.4/gshell-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.4/maven-reporting-api-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-apt-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-fml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/Durgesh/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gossip/gossip/1.2/gossip-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Please find attached pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.wu.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>bdd_geb_spock</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <skipITTests>false</skipITTests>
        <geb.version>2.1</geb.version>
        <selenium.version>3.6.0</selenium.version>      
        <groovy.version>2.4.14</groovy.version>      
        <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.2</gson.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.3.4</httpclient.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.3.2</httpcore.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.21.0</surefire.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <serenity.version>1.9.2</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.9.2</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.3</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <tags></tags>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
            <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
            <version>${geb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gebish/geb-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
            <artifactId>geb-core</artifactId>
            <version>${geb.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dependencies related to GEB SPOCK reporting-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- this avoids affecting your version of Groovy/Spock -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- // if you don't already have slf4j-api and an implementation of it in the classpath, add this! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Serenity related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipITTests}</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*Spec.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
                        <!--<geb.build.reportsDir>target/reports</geb.build.reportsDir>-->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Maven gmaven plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <!--<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>1.4</version>-->
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                    <source/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                        <!--<version>1.4</version>-->
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spock.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Serenity Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>${tags}</tags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Sonar Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please help me to execute test cases from command line as its successfully getting executed by Intellij.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GMaven 2.x](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/index.html) should not be used for Groovy compilation anymore according to its own web site:

> ### No Compilation Support
>
> GMaven 2.x no longer supports any integration for compilation of Groovy sources. There were too many problems with stub-generation and hooking up compliation to the proper Maven lifecycle phases to effectivly support.
>
> For compliation integration with Maven please see the ***Groovy Eclipse Compiler***, which is the recommended and prefered option.

So I updated your POM a bit - I wanted to fix a few more things, but didn't - by just adding Groovy Eclipse support to the Maven Compiler:

```xml
<!-- Groovy compiler for Spock/Geb tests -->
<version.groovy-eclipse-compiler>2.9.2-01</version.groovy-eclipse-compiler>
<version.groovy-eclipse-batch>2.4.3-01</version.groovy-eclipse-batch>
```

```xml
  <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
      <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
      <!-- IMPORTANT -->
      <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
      <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-compiler}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
        <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-batch}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-compiler}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
  </plugin>
```

Now `mvn clean test` works:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bdd_geb_spock 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_GebSpockMavenProblem\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- groovy-eclipse-compiler:2.9.2-01:add-groovy-build-paths (default-add-groovy-build-paths) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Adding /src/main/groovy to the list of source folders
[INFO] Adding /src/test/groovy to the list of test source folders
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_GebSpockMavenProblem\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ bdd_geb_spock ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_GebSpockMavenProblem\target\surefire-reports\2018-03-27T19-42-16_167-jvmRun1.dumpstream
[INFO] Running spec.sprintOne.TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec
[main] INFO com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.ConfigLoader - SpockReports config loaded: {com.athaydes.spockframework.report.showCodeBlocks=false, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.reportFileExtension=md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.testSourceRoots=src/test/groovy, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.IReportCreator=com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.outputDir=build/spock-reports, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.inlineCss=true, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.featureReportCss=spock-feature-report.css, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.hideEmptyBlocks=false, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.summaryReportCss=spock-summary-report.css, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.projectVersion=Unknown, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.specTemplateFile=/templateReportCreator/spec-template.md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.summaryTemplateFile=/templateReportCreator/summary-template.md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.excludeToc=false, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.enabled=true, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.projectName=, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.summaryFileName=summary.md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.printThrowableStackTrace=false, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.enabled=true}
Hello test!
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.308 s - in spec.sprintOne.TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The full POM - is here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>net.wu.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>bdd_geb_spock</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <skipITTests>false</skipITTests>
    <geb.version>2.1</geb.version>
    <selenium.version>3.6.0</selenium.version>
    <groovy.version>2.4.14</groovy.version>
    <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
    <gson.version>2.8.2</gson.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.3.4</httpclient.version>
    <httpcore.version>4.3.2</httpcore.version>
    <surefire.plugin.version>2.21.0</surefire.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Groovy compiler for Spock/Geb tests -->
    <version.groovy-eclipse-compiler>2.9.2-01</version.groovy-eclipse-compiler>
    <version.groovy-eclipse-batch>2.4.3-01</version.groovy-eclipse-batch>

    <serenity.version>1.9.2</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>1.9.2</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.3</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <tags></tags>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
      <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
      <version>${geb.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gebish/geb-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
      <artifactId>geb-core</artifactId>
      <version>${geb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>${gson.version}</version>
      <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dependencies related to GEB SPOCK reporting-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <!-- this avoids affecting your version of Groovy/Spock -->
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- // if you don't already have slf4j-api and an implementation of it in the classpath, add this! -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Serenity related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skipITTests}</skipTests>
          <includes>
            <include>*Spec.*</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
            <!--<geb.build.reportsDir>target/reports</geb.build.reportsDir>-->
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          <!-- IMPORTANT -->
          <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-compiler}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-batch}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${version.groovy-eclipse-compiler}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Serenity Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <tags>${tags}</tags>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Sonar Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.905</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I also welcome your other suggestions as well which you mentioned that you wanted to fix some more. Thank you.